# How to apply new changes to current database in code fist EF core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a project that coded with DotNet Core code first.

Now, there is a lot of real data on the database and i have to add some features with many tables and new relations to this project.

How can I apply these tables and their relations to the Database without adding manually?

Is there any way to use Add-Migratiosn and Update-Database to apply new changes via EF core instead of manually applying?

Comment: Why did you choose code first instead of scaffolding the existing database?

Comment: Because I have started this project from scratch with code first and its database made by code first update-database command for the first time. And so far I have applied all changes in my database manually (after first initial create)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not many changes to your DBContext you can remove it and use Scaffolding to create new DbContext from the existing database schema. You can find more information in the official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding).

It is better to use only one entity framework database approach either Database-First or Code-First.